# How to diagnose flaky nslookup/bind9?

Tags: bind, nslookup

**BACKGROUND**

I have a long running DNS (bind9) server running on Ubuntu that works most of the time (from Ubuntu, Win8 or OSX):

```
$ nslookup gitserver
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Name:   gitserver.foobar.com
Address: 172.17.51.3
```

However, I periodically get a lookup error:

```
$ nslookup gitserver
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find gitserver: NXDOMAIN
```

Note that I have bind9 configured with an outward facing names and inward facing.  fwiw, gitserver is on the inward facing side.

Also, if I try the lookup 3 or 4 times, it usually starts to work again.

**QUESTION**

What can I do to diagnose the cause of this intermittent problem?

Comment: Learn to use dig.

Comment: @Iain I know about dig - will try it the next time I have the issue, but I suspect something is wrong with my DNS configuration (as opposed to nslookup in this case)...